# How to upload image to graphql server in android studio?

Tags: android, graphql

I am new to graphql and I am trying to upload an image to the graphql server and I don't know how to start. I am using the images from the gallery. The document says to convert the file into an Upload scalar as such

If you're on Android/JVM, you can turn a File into an upload

`val upload = File.toUpload("application/json")`

On multiplatform, you can use DefaultUpload

```
val upload = DefaultUpload.Builder()
              .fileName("filename.txt")
              .content { sink ->
                okioSource.use { sink.writeAll(it) }
              }
              .build()
```

I tried creating the file from the uri as such

```
val file = uri.toFile()
```

and creating the upload variable as

```
val upload = file.toUpload("application/json")
```

But it is giving me
"open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)" error
I couldn't find related documents or examples.